# Hive Beeline outputs ^M and null char

Tags: hadoop, hive, null, control-characters, beeline

I want to get the output from a Hive query running beeline. For some reasons, I get ^M and "null" char along with expected results.

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://server:10000/default --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --silent=true --showWarnings=false --verbose=false -f ./logs/runme.sql
```

content of runme.sql

```
select distinct(date_format(cast(epoch_dt/1000 as TIMESTAMP), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')) from mydb.mytab;
```

I put the results in an array like

```
tmp_cmd="beeline -u jdbc:hive2://server:10000/default --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --silent=true --showWarnings=false --verbose=false -f ./logs/runme.sql"
echo $tmp_cmd
cmd_ent_id=($(eval "$tmp_cmd"))
```

The results looks like this

```
^Mnull20181016075150
20181016080129
 <---- empty line
```

I only want to the values.

Comment: I think you can't avoid null as it is data. can you share the sample values where you get null.. will work out

Comment: I've read this HDR community thread https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/151839/issue-empty-rows-in-the-beeline-output-even-with-s.html and was able to get it cleanup if running it at cmd prompt. However, if I run it in a bash script, it does not.